# Why websites have an indirect way for showing user profile pictures?

Tags: php, image

So I have been developing a website that has accounts and each account has it's own profile picture (something like a social media website), and due to security and good measures, I save profile pictures in a folder outside the webroot on my server; so surely I can't make an html image element access an image outside webroot, so I had to make a PHP script that serves this image, so I came out with a simple script serving the image, and to render the image I just do the following:

```
<img src="/serve-profile-picture-by-user-id.php?id=10006">
```

That's too simple, clear and easy to understand, which I don't know if it is a bad thing or a good thing, while when for example seeing how Twitter or Facebook serve their profile pictures using the "inspect element", I find divs inside divs inside divs each div having a very long id and some weird things, Why they do this?

In a nutshell, why do websites choose sophisticated ways of showing a profile image while a simple script with a simple URL can be used? Is it due to server load management? or security related problems? Or it's just how every website implements it?

Comment: A lot to unpack here, I think it's too broad as asked - but the premise of what you've described working for the sites you're comparing to is .. well false - at scale (and that could be having 100k users) the simple script you've described would likely not perform too well. Some  leading questions: Why do you think it is secure/a-good-practice to write uploaded files outside the webroot AND to serve requests for those images via PHP? How fast is it to find a file in a folder with 10k+ other files in it? Am hoping there's not db logic involved in `serve-profile-picture-by-user-id.php` :)

Comment: @AD7six Concerning saving in a folder outside webroot comes to the fact that I **think** webroot shall only have website files or documents not profile pictures and stuff like that, plus don't worry The example I used as a code here is just for simplicity, there ain't any db logic in my real code :) well in fact I am using a framework and the rendered image element has a src URL different than the one stated in the question, but just has the same idea; the URL is very straight forward and easy to understand.

Comment: `<div>`s are used for layout. That's entirely separate from serving the image.